# What are the documents we need to carry for flight journey within India?

Tags: india, paperwork, domestic-travel

I need to go Kolkata from Vijayawada by air but don't have a passport. I do have a valid voter card, an [Aadhaar card](https://uidai.gov.in/new/) and a [PAN card](https://www.myutiitsl.com/PAN_ONLINE/PANApp).

What are the documents I need to carry?

Answer (score 15):

From Air India:

> For domestic travel within India, valid photo identification, namely, a passport, Income Tax PAN Card, Voter’s ID or Driving license is mandatory. Any other relevant concessionary fare IDs should be carried as they need to be displayed if required.

Answer (score 9):

Domestic flights in India accept any government issued photo identification including but not limited to Passport, PAN card, Voter ID card, Driving licence, Aadhaar Card.
I have traveled in domestic flights of Air India, SpiceJet, IndiGo, GoAir and Air Asia just showing my PAN Card. So PAN card should not be an issue unless the name on booked ticket doesn't match with the PAN card.